# C++: implicit linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

Why is this not a more popular idiom/pattern?

```
#include <list>
class A {
  int data;
  static std::list<A*> glist;
public: 
  A():data(0) {
    glist.push_back(this);
  }
  ~A() {
    glist.remove(this);
  }
};
```

It's like a safety net. You can delete an instance of `A` from any pointer to it and the list manages itself. Isn't this so much better than creating separate containers to keep track of your `A`'s and making mistakes managing them? I guess I'm making a big deal out of something really basic. But I bet this could have saved me lots of debug time in the past.

Comment: Speed and overhead? and as in silico below stated. i missed the static :o)

Comment: This would crash and burn spectacularly (and unpredictably!) if you use instances of `A` in different threads.

Comment: @In silico: Of course, many things will do that if you have no mutex'. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve.  "You can delete ...A... from any pointer" - sure, are you then suggesting every delete should do a linear O(N) search in the list before deciding whether to do that delete?

Comment: @Xeo: Of course. What I was trying to get at is that the OP's code costs a lot (overhead/speed/space/etc) for very little or no benefit (I can't see how the OP's code can help with anything). :-)

Comment: @In silico: That aside. ;) It just bugs me that every example that could explode in a multithreaded environment is taken as that. I think (or atleast hope) that with the basic understanding of multithreading, one knows of mutex' and uses them when the program is indeed multithreaded. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not thread safe. Sometimes you're already maintaining the object list and don't care. Objects on the stack don't really need to be tracked in another container. It introduces a new dependency of your class that may not be needed. I'm sure there are many more reasons I missed.

The object management issues aren't issues if you use `shared_ptr` or boost's ptr containers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem would be the static keyword. You can have only one *global* list - no separate lists, since the static keyword would ensure that all instances of your A class will belong to one and only list; you will not be able to create separate lists of A's. If that is indeed your intention, then this should be fine. However, I would also add that there is unnecessary redundancy here - std::list internally manages these things for you - I don't understand why you would want to add an extra layer of abstraction over it.

Comment: Suppose I had class `B` derive from `A`. Do instances of `B` go in the same list?

Comment: Yes, they would go into the same list, since when you call B's constructor, A's constructor would be implicitly called, which would insert it into the list.